# Why does margin-top get applied to the containing element here?

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this has been asked many times but I couldn't work out what to search for.

I have the following HTML and CSS ([see jsfiddle for a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/J99jj/)):

```
<!--HTML-->
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>



/* CSS */
#container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}

#header ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 20px; /* I want this to be the margin at the top of the ul, not the container */
}

#header li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

The problem I'm having is with the `margin-top` of the `<ul>`. It's adding space above the `#container` `<div>`, not above the `<ul>`. I must be missing something fundamental about CSS, because I just don't *get* this behaviour. Could someone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to margin collapsing, if it touches the top of the body then that's where the margin lives. Easy fix is to just rely on top padding.

Comment: Ah, now I know what it's called! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the padding. I've also found that using a CSS reset is helpful in getting everything to behave more similarly across browsers.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using a CSS reset in the real thing, but I get the same effect.